# Opencv assertion failed <size.width>0 && <size.height>0 in cv::imshow

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv\cvaux.h>
#include<opencv\cxcore.h>
#include <opencv2\imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>




using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void main()

{

Mat src = imread("greyscale.jpg"); \\image to be edited
imshow("input", src);
Mat dest; \\processed image
threshold(src, dest, 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
imshow("result", dest);
waitKey();
}
```

The above code when executed on Visual Studio 2013 express (configured for opencv 3.0)
does not show any compiling errors.
However the output window displays error

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, fi
le C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\highgui\src\windo
w.cpp, line 271
Press any key to continue . . .
And window pops up saying open cv has crashed.

I'm new to opencv and any help would be much appreciated.Thanks in advance!
**I have gone through similar problems but theirs were dude to the webcam feed being null initially..all im doing here is scanning an image**

Comment: add if(src.empty ()) {cout << "loading image failed << endl; return 0;}  right after imread line. please try to provide full path e.g. "C:/yourdata/greyscale.jpg" because you might have a wrong relative path there.

Comment: if that works you either have to load as grayscale (imread("greyscale.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);) or convert to grayscale after loading before thresholding.

Comment: Is `greyscale.jpg` in the current folder of the application? Unless you changed the settings in visual studio this is the folder with the project file not the executable.

Comment: Yep it is in the same folder as the project file.

Comment: No..it doesnt print loading image failed on adding the line you suggested @Micka

Comment: I found my mistake.Apparently the file extension was jpeg and not jpg.i Thought they were interchangable.apparently not!